# Override /secur/NoAccess.jsp page in Salesforce org

Tags: force.com

I am trying to show some custom message instead of "Insufficient Privileges" when user get the NoAccess.jsp page.
So is it possible to override this standard page with custom page or I can put some more message in this page.

Comment: I don't think it will be possible. But you can try to check if user has access of this but you can't override this.

Comment: If its running on communities / sites, you can specify custom 403 page.

Comment: Its not community .Its standard org.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way that's already built in for any custom page that I'd expect could possibly be implemented using global variables from the link to a page or record if coming from a standard page. From [the Visualforce Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_std_checking_accessibility.htm), here's how it's done.

You can check for the accessibility of an object like this:

```
{!$ObjectType.objectname.accessible}
```

To ensure that a portion of your page will display only if a user has access to an object, use the render attribute on a component. For example, to display a page block if a user has access to the Lead object, you would do the following:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead">
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!$ObjectType.Lead.accessible}">
        <p>This text will display if you can see the Lead object.</p>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

It is good practice to provide an alternative message if a user cannot access an object. For example:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead">
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!$ObjectType.Lead.accessible}">
        <p>This text will display if you can see the Lead object.</p>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="NOT({!$ObjectType.Lead.accessible})">
        <p>Sorry, but you cannot see the data because you do not have access to the Lead object.</p>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```